# Trying to create a nested for loop that uses two user input values

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, increment

I'm trying to create a nested for loop that uses two user input values where value 1 equals the number of rows and value 2 equals the number to increment by. If the user enters 5 for both values, the output should be like this:
0
5 10
15 20 25
30 35 40 45
50 55 60 65 70

So far I have this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows: ");
            int number= myScan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the number to increment by: ");
            int number2= myScan.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    for(int k = 0; k <=number2 + number; k++)
                    System.out.print(number + " ");

            System.out.println(" ");
    }

}}}
```

I know that I messed up somewhere within my coding. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think your code is wrong?

Comment: I haven't been able to get the correct output yet. It looks like this right now:  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5...ect. basically a block of 5's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the third `for` loop (the one with `int k`).
You can write it this way:

```
int incr = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
       System.out.print((incr++) * number2 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'inc' is the amount to increment by and that 'rows' is the number of rows

```
int num = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex <= row; nIndex++) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
        num += inc;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class lem;

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

int i,j,n=1,m=0;

Scanner ab=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the number : ");

int num=ab.nextInt();

for(i=1;i<=num;i++)

{

for(j=0;j

n=5*m;

m++;

System.out.print(n+" ");

}

System.out.println();

}}}